# Using A Specific rows ID as a Variable on Insert SQL

Tags: insert, sql-server-2012

Ok i have 3 tables

Person
Item
Purchase

Person has 2 columns: PersonId, PersonName
Item has 2 columns: ItemId, ItemName
Purchase has 3 columns: PurchaseId, ItemId, PersonId

Lets Say Person with a PersonName of "Justin" Has a PersonId of 2
and Item with an ItemName of "Book" Has an ItemId of 4

I would like to insert into the purchase table using the values 2 and 4

What i have so far

```
 Select PersonId  AS a FROM tblPerson
 Where PersonName = 'Justin'

 Select ItemId  AS b From tblItem
 Where ItemName = 'Book'

 INSERT INTO tblPurchase (ItemId,PersonId)
 VALUES (b,a);
```

So the new entry in Purchase would be

PurchaseId   ItemId   PersonId
1            4        2

How would i do this in sql? Would i use variables?

Im using SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @PersonId INT
DECLARE @ItemId INT

Select @PersonId = PersonId FROM tblPerson
Where PersonName = 'Justin'

Select @ItemId = ItemId From tblItem
Where ItemName = 'Book'

  INSERT INTO tblPurchase (ItemId,PersonId)
  VALUES (@ItemId  ,@PersonId);
```

If you are using an Identity or auto generated key on tblPurchase you can get that key after the INSERT using:

```
DECLARE @NewKey INT
SET @NewKey = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: I hope there are UNIQUE INDEXes/CONSTRAINTs on `dbo.tblPerson.PersonName` and on `dbo.tblItem.ItemName`.